# How to build a single 'flag' checkbox in prestashop with form helpers?

Tags: forms, checkbox, prestashop, helper

I can't figure out from official docs how to build a single checkbox element from the standard helpers. I already have the relevant boolean  entity in database and I can build radios or selects as well for it, and they work.

But what I'd really like is to have a single checkbox to use as a boolean flag.

Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, the answer is to just use the 'switch' type: that will build a 'slider' switch on backoffice page. For future reference, I'm gonna report 3 different ways to accomplish the same task: radio, select and switch.

They have all been tested on AdminAddressesController and are bound to a custom DB boolean field called 'expo'.

```
//SELECT

$s_options = array(
  array( 'expo' => 1, 'name' => 'Yes' ),
  array( 'expo' => 0, 'name' => 'No' )
);
$temp_fields[] = array(
  'type' => 'select',
  'label' => $this->l('Is Expo'),
  'name' => 'expo',
  'required' => false,
  'options' => array(
    'query' => $s_options,
    'id' => 'expo',
    'name' => 'name'
  )
);

//RADIO

$s_options = array(
  array( 'id' => 'expo_on', 'value' => 1, 'label' => $this->l('Yes')),
  array( 'id' => 'expo_off', 'value' => 0, 'label' => $this->l('No')),
);
$temp_fields[] = array(
  'type' => 'radio',
  'label' => $this->l('Is Expo'),
  'name' => 'expo',
  'required' => false,
  'class' => 't',
  'is_bool' => true,
  'values' => $s_options
);

//SWITCH

$s_options = array(
  array( 'id' => 'expo_on', 'value' => 1, 'label' => $this->l('Yes')),
  array( 'id' => 'expo_off', 'value' => 0, 'label' => $this->l('No')),
);
$temp_fields[] = array(
  'type' => 'switch',
  'label' => $this->l('Is Expo'),
  'name' => 'expo',
  'required' => false,
  'is_bool' => true,
  'values' => $s_options
);
```